# Why is there whitish gunk in my fridge water even after changing the filter

Tags: appliances, refrigerator

Why is there white filaments like in the water coming out of our fridge? We have changed the water filter 2 weeks ago, still no improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Found this on [Appliance 411](http://www.appliance411.com/faq/white-particles.shtml):

> I have heard a number of complaints recently that the chemicals (specifically chloramine - a mixture of chlorine and ammonia) used in some water treatment facilities are causing the material the molded plastic refrigerator water reservoirs are made from to break down resulting in white or whitish particles appearing as flakes, flecks or specs in the dispensed chilled water. In that case the water filter is not usually the cause, instead replacing of the chilled water reservoir itself may be necessary.
>
> Most manufacturers originally used a molded plastic water reservoir which is what seems to be effected and breaking down. Many fridge manufacturers are now selling a coil of plastic tubing (like that used in the rest of the refrigerator's water system) in place of a molded plastic reservoir.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately since you waited until after the problem started to replace the filter, your tap water likely reacted with the plastic in the refrigerator causing these white particles. If your refrigerator will allow you to dispense water without a filter attached, I would remove the filter and flush the system with unfiltered tap water by dispensing water from the refrigerator until the white particles are gone. This may take a lot of time and water, so that's why I recommend removing the filter to speed up the process and to not filter water that is going to be discarded. After the white particles have been removed, then reattach the filter and flush once or twice more to fill the system with filtered water to prevent it from happening again.

If you cannot dispense water while the filter is removed, dispense water while the filter is attached to flush the system.

Flushing your system by dispensing water from it will remove the white particles and solve the problem. Furthermore, If you want to prevent this from happening again then you either need to replace the filter more often (before it happens again), or add an additional activated carbon filter on the water line before it connects to your refrigerator. The preferred setup is having two activated carbon filters in series to make sure that anything the first filter missed will get captured by the second filter at least until the next service interval when both filters are replaced.

Most refrigerators with filters have a 1 stage carbon filter, but expensive ones have 2 stage carbon filters. If you want the ultimate water quality, you can remove the refrigerator filter and install a reverse osmosis water filter that feeds the refrigerator too. Adding a reverse osmosis system is a much larger project, but I'm including it in this answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

My LG refrigerator is brand new (December 1, 2022) and from purchase continually emits a buildup of white piles of particles on the flat ledge that holds the glass and even drops down onto the refrigerator handles and the floor. The LG tech said the white powder is coming from the molded plastic water reservoir. Those particles have marred the finish on the ledge underneath the dispenser.

Answer (score 0):

In December 2022, I purchased an LG LRFVC2406 refrigerator with a door ice/water dispenser and a craft ice maker in the lower freezer compartment.

There is no residue in the craft ice or in the areas/bucket in the lower compartment. Letting a craft ice ball melt and water dry in a clear glass reveals no white powder. The same with a few ice cubes removed from the top of the ice bin located in the door leading to the dispenser cavity.

The retailer was quickly notified of the issue. They contacted LG who sent out a so called "service tech". Without inspecting the door or dispenser cavity he stated the white powder was due to calcium in the water (however, in my area the water is great and no one complains of water deposits). He immediately checked to see what water filter was in use (it was the LG filter that came with the refrigerator) - my thought was he made this check in order to be able to void the LG warranty if a non-LG filter was being used. He removed/took out the original filter, replaced it with a new LG filter and claimed that sometimes the LG filters are bad.

I support the idea of the above comment that it is some substance coming from inside the door panel itself. I took a picture up into the door cavity with my iphone and it shows wiring and connections present which allow ice and moisture from the ice to drip across. This is not normal as I went back to several stores and took pictures up into the door cavities and they appeared sealed and had no exposed wiring/connections. I suggest you all  try the picture method too - I had to use the selfie mode to produce like and the angle.

I am now in the process of filing a complaint with my state Consumer Protection department. What is good as typically the state office will forward the information to compiled nationwide with the FTC.

So far, the white powder issue remains, even with more abundance. I turned off the ice makers soon after the technician. Tried to lock the control panel, the buttons are not responding. So far LG has not remedied the situation.